# How to load different storyboard for today widget?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, today-extension

I Googled a lot to find out the way to set different storyboard for today widget, as I need different layout design for iPhone and iPad, but I did not find any relevant solution for that. Some solution is for loading separate storyboard for the main App but that solutions are not working for Today Widget (App Extension).

Comment: you want to load 5 storyboards?

Comment: No two storyboard, one for iPhone and other for iPad, because my layout design is different.